# JSON-LD error in SDTT: "Missing ',' or ']' in array declaration."

Tags: json-ld

My JSON-LD below gives me an error on Google's Structured Data Testing-tool:

> Missing ',' or ']' in array declaration.

I have spent hours on the below but cannot figure where or what I have done wrong.

```html
 <script type="application/ld+json">  
  {  
"@context": "http://schema.org",
"@type": "WebSite",
"name": "the business name",
"url": "https://www.the business domain name.com",
"logo": "https://www.the business domain name.com/images/schema/businesslogo.png",
"description": "wibble and more wibble content",
"telephone": "1234566453,
"areaServed": ["London"],  
"openingHoursSpecification": [
{
  "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
  "dayOfWeek": [
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday"
  ],
  "opens": "07:00",
  "closes": "18:00"
}     
  "openingHoursSpecification": [
{
  "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
  "dayOfWeek": [
    "Saturday"
  ],
  "opens": "07:00",
  "closes": "13:00"
}
],  
"address": {
"@type": "PostalAddress",
  "streetAddress": "address here",      
  "addressRegion": "London",
  "postalCode":"postcode here"
},
"geo": {
"@type": "GeoCoordinates",
"latitude": "",
"longitude": ""
},
"sameAs" : [ "https://twitter.com/mytwitteraccountname",
"https://www.facebook.com/myfacebookaccountname",
"https://www.pinterest.co.uk/mypinterestaccname/",
 "https:www.linkedin.com/in/professional-tilers-london" ]
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not properly closing "openingHoursSpecification.": [

Paste your code in a linter and you will see the error.

https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: thank you I tried that only to get the following.

Error: Parse error on line 1:
    < script type = "app
    ^
    Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got       'undefined'

Comment: You don't want to have your <script> tags in the test, just the JSON.